# Best container for message bus

Tags: c++, thread-safety, components, containers, messaging

I am designing my own message bus in C++, which will serve as the back-end for a component based game. The message bus will have the following characteristics:

- Frequently iterated through, starting at the first element and ending at the last.
- Infrequent removal of elements at random locations
- Theoretically limitless number of elements
- Theoretically limitless number of message types
- Needs to run as fast as possible
- All elements will contain a pointer to the message handler
- Thread safe

**My question is:**

What is the best container to store such information? This is not limited to standard C++, so boost containers are applicable so long as the container is cross platform between Windows and Linux.

Comment: Something thread safe, that's for sure.

Comment: Infrequent removal of elements at random locations - Does that mean random but has just been searched for or random as in array index random?

Comment: @sarien An object may unsubscribe from a certain message at any given time.

Comment: Not so sure, you're in the right place for this question here! From the guts I would say the question isn't which (STL?) container to use for a message bus (internally), but which message distribution infrastructure is used for it is the crucial point for such design. You might have a look at messaging services like [0MQ](http://zeromq.org/), [OpenAMQ](http://www.openamq.org/), [Windows MessageQueue](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6129/Using-WIN32-Message-Queue-in-C-WIN32-Multithreaded), [CORBA](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture) or alike.

Comment: @g-makulik thank you very much for the links, however I would like to make it myself as a learning tool :)

Comment: @JoshuaGerrard Then you might be interested in reading about [EAI Messaging Patterns/MessageBus](http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessageBus.html) (and the ff. of course).

Comment: Thank you again! If you put your comments into an answer, with advantages and disadvantages our alternatives that would be even better and useful for anyone else with a similar problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Message Bus is a complex thing and doesn't barely boil down to the representation of a message queue for a single component that is connected to the bus.
As mentioned in a comment, `std::queue<MessageType,std::list<MessageType> >` should fulfill your primary use cases besides thread safety, but theres a lot more things to consider.

Here's a **sample** for a thread safe queue implementation: [EventQueue.h](https://github.com/makulik/sttcl/blob/master/sttcl/include/EventQueue.h) from [STTCL](http://makulik.github.io/sttcl/). If you place in `std::queue<__T__,std::list<__T__> >` as value of `STTCL_DEFAULT_DEQUEIMPL(__T__)` it should fit your needs, including the `find()` operation for a particular item.

Depending on your application's use cases you'll need to choose from various messaging patterns for distribution and subscription for certain types of messages.
When I was about to deal with these topics, I found the [EAI catalog of messaging patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/index.html) extremely useful.

Besides this: Always (**ALWAYS!!!** *Yes! **Three** exclamation marks*) **depart** message payload from transport!!

A notable transport system for messaging patterns is [0MQ](http://zeromq.org/), which provides bindings for various languages. But others are available for C++ implementations (including raw socket based implementations or s.th. like [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)).

As for the design of message payload, I found [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) most useful, portable and flexible for all my requirements in distributed systems (including embedded!).

Comment: Some of this seems a bit beyond me, I've got a lot of reading to do! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

**std::list**

- O(1) Iteration
- O(1) Removal (Assuming you have an iterator)
- O(1) Insertion

The main disadvantage of lists is that they lack random access, which is however irrelevant for message queues.

Comment: What do you mean by, "assuming you have an iterator"?

Comment: An iterator pointing to the element to be removed. (`list.erase(it)`)

Comment: This assumption is not (necessarily) correct. An element could request its immediate removal without knowing where it is in the list.

Comment: Removing an element at an unknown position takes O(n) time, which is not that bad considering that removals are infrequent.

Comment: Could you add a comparison with other potential candidates to the answer? Thank you for your answer so far by the way :)

Comment: @JoshuaGerrard `std::queue<MessageType,std::list<MessageType> >` should be fine to fulfill your requirements (for internal representation). You'll need to add synchronization on top (thread safety).